# Is a rollover on a lightbox close (X) button possible?

Tags: wordpress, lightbox

I've tried the traditional Javascript rollover method and CSS background switching method, but nothing seems to work -- apparently when you're hovering over the close button you're actually...not.

Using Lightbox Gallery plugin in Wordpress.

Any suggestions?

Have a good one,

Andrew

Comment: do you have the original html+css+js code? show us so that we know what to answer.

Answer (score 0):

> button you're actually...not.
>   Indeed, You're actually hovering the whole picture (except the right and left third which is for next/prev button).
>   Try using [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/), Use it and you'll know what are you really hovering over.